# Selenium with an Excel doc

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation

Im new in automation with Selenium and even with JAVA...im trying to fill a form with information i already have in an excel doc  but for some reason i get an error "The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type String".. i know i have all the Imports and dependencies but i dont know where im doing it wrong...

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='First Name']")
    WebElement firstName;
        
    //2. Last Name 
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Last Name']")
    WebElement lastName;
    
    //3. Email
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='name@example.com']")
    WebElement email;
    
    //4. Gender
    @FindBy(xpath="//label[normalize-space()='Female']")
    WebElement gender;      
    //5. Mobile Number
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Mobile Number']")
    WebElement mobileNumber;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you're calling sendKeys() method on a string.

Comment: Hello, no it's not that.. the problem was that i gave the same name to the String and the WebElement... i modified the string name and it worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.. the problem was that i gave the same name to the String and the WebElement... i modified the String name and the code worked correct![image]